# SalesForce to Kafka using the new Pub/Sub API

Tags: apache-kafka, salesforce

I am trying to figure out the best way to write Salesforce Data to a Kafka topic.
I want the Kafka topic to be a state store, not containing only the changed fields (delta topic).

SalesForce recommends using their new Pub/Sub API based on gRPC but I see it only supports platform events and CDC:

- I don't like using CDC as it only contains the changed fields and then a Kafka streams app would have to be built to create a full state object based on all the changes. This is too much effort and also performance might not be that good when joining all the changes
- I don't like also the platform event solution because you can define a custom schema but then you have to write custom Apex code to publish data to your platform event, too much effort as well

I think it would be best to use pushTopic but unfortunately it's no longer supported by SalesForce and therefore it's not available in their new Pub/Sub API. Do you have any idea what would be the best way by using Pub/Sub API to receive a full state of the object (containing all fields) every time some of the object field changes?

Comment: Kafka Streams aggregate function makes sense to me

Comment: Platform events came be published with non-code tools also in Salesforce and not just with apex code.

Comment: If you do a one time load of data to create full state objects then cdc will be best option and you can keep getting delta updates using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enrich the CDC's with extra fields. Those could maybe be enough in your case.

[Enrich Change Events with Extra Fields When Subscribed with CometD or Pub/Sub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_enrich_intro.htm)

Comment: The only downside of this approach is that the CDC cannot be enriched with more than 10 fields

Comment: 10 fields...what a pointless feature.